# Logging instrumentation on any button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm looking for the simplest way to instrument my client side instrumentation by having any button run some JS logging what button was clicked, some interesting user data then perform it's necessary functionality.

I realize I could hook up this logging to each function call individually, but I'm looking for a more intelligent approach that allows me to setup this call on any number of event types.

Would it be better to use jQuery and do something like:

```
$("input[type=button]").click(loggingFn);
```

Or does AngularJS have a more intelligent way of doing this?

Comment: As click propagates, you can just set up the `ng-click` handler that'll check the original event target on the `app` element.

Comment: I'd have to attach an ng-click method to each item I'd like logged then correct?

Comment: If you have just some elements you want to be tracked, it's better just to set up a common handler for `ng-click` (or, if you wish, a common directive with the same purpose). I thought you want to track click on each and every element. ) For that purpose you'll need to have just a single click handler set up on the root element of your application, then check event's originalTarget property.

Comment: This guy did something similar to what you're tying to do: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2422-capturing-document-click-events-with-angularjs.htm